# Update div on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which updates the div with id "DTE" to the date in the divs with class "date" that are scrolled past. It works as you scroll down however I would like it to work in a slightly different way scrolling back up.
So for example once "03 Dec 2016" is scrolled past DTE updates to 03 Dec 2016 as expected, however I would like when the page is scrolled back up as DTE becomes higher relative to the top than "03 Dec 2016" for DTE to be updated to the previous date in this case "02 Dec 2016". I don't want to wait until I scroll to 02 Dec 2016 foe DTE to be updated. So anywhere in the region with text related to whichever day DTE will reflect that day. I'm probably missing something obvious

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');

        $(window).on("scroll resize", function(){

          var pos=$('#DTE').offset();
          $('.date').each(function() {
            if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top &&
                pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
              $('#DTE').html($(this).attr("date"));
              return; 
            } 
          });
        });
      });   
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="DTE" style="position: fixed; height:15px; font-size:70%; border-radius: 3px; background-color:lightcyan; text-align:center; width:11.8%; margin-left:34.55%; color:black"></div>
    <p>   
    <div class="date" date="02 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">02 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 02 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 50px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 02 Dec 2016</p>
    <br/>
    <div class="date" date="03 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">03 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 03 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 50px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 03 Dec 2016</p>
    <br/> 
    <div class="date" date="04 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">04 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 04 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 50px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 04 Dec 2016</p>
    <br/>   
    <div class="date" date="05 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">05 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 05 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 500px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 05 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a way to use [`$.prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) where you call the previous element. You can probably use that or something like that to get the previous elements attributes.

Comment: @TimRoberts I've tried it $.prev did not work for some reason. I tried $('#DTE').html($(this).prev().attr("date")) and it did not return anything

Comment: btw, there is an open `<p>` tag after `#DTE`.  you probably need to close that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [jQuery's nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) along with the `class="date"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('scroll');

    $(window).on("scroll resize", function(){
      var pos = $('#DTE').offset();

      $('#DTE2').html(pos.top);

      $('.date').each(function() {

        // you need the next class="date"
        // so go next UNTIL you reach it
        var nxt = $(this).nextUntil('.date');

        // then get the "next" element's pos.top which will be the date
        var nextpostop = nxt.next().offset().top;

        if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top &&
            pos.top <= nextpostop) {
          $('#DTE').html($(this).attr("date"));
          return;
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');

        $(window).on("scroll resize", function(){
          var pos = $('#DTE').offset();

          $('#DTE2').html(pos.top);

          $('.date').each(function() {

            // you need the next class="date"
            // so go next UNTIL you reach it
            var nxt = $(this).nextUntil('.date');

            // then get the "next" element's pos.top which will be the date
            var nextposbot = nxt.next().offset().top + nxt.next().height();

            if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top &&
                pos.top <= nextposbot) {
              $('#DTE').html($(this).attr("date"));
              return;
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="DTE" style="position: fixed; height:15px; font-size:70%; border-radius: 3px; background-color:lightcyan; text-align:center; width:11.8%; margin-left:34.55%; color:black"></div>
 
    <div class="date" date="02 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">02 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 02 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 50px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 02 Dec 2016</p>
    <br/>
    <div class="date" date="03 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">03 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 03 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 50px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 03 Dec 2016</p>
    <br/> 
    <div class="date" date="04 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">04 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 04 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 50px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 04 Dec 2016</p>
    <br/>   
    <div class="date" date="05 Dec 2016" style="height:15px; font-size:70%; background-color:#2E64FE; text-align:center; width:15%; margin-left:44%; color:white">05 Dec 2016</div>
    <p style="height: 100px; margin-left: 44%">Text related to 05 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
    <p style="height: 500px; margin-left: 44%">More text related to 05 Dec 2016</p> 
    <br/>
```

Comment: almost perfect however is it possible to get the date to update the moment the you scroll back up past a date say from 03 Dec 2016 back into 02 Dec 2016 text area so as soon as that is below DTE can it be updated? In your code the date updates about half way through scrolling up the previous div

Comment: i added the height of the next offset `var nextposbot = nxt.next().offset().top + nxt.next().height();` but from here, you should be able to tweak it to perfection.  i would gather that "getting" that next `class="date"` was the trick, everything else is adjustment.